# Selenium Automatic element click returns null

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have written a automation test case in selenium to test login page and should click forgot password link.Browser opens and goes to the url given but forgot password link isn't automatically clicking ,Can someone tell whats the problem with my code.

**BaseCode**

```
public class Forgetpsw {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void Browseropen() throws Exception {
        Browsers startup=new  Browsers();
        startup.Initiating();
    }

    @Test
    public void Forget(String username) throws Exception{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Forgot Password?']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000L);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='User ID'][@id='forgotPasswordForm:j_idt13:0:username']")).sendKeys(username);
    }
}
```

**Browsers.java**

```
public class Browsers {
    public  WebDriver driver;

    public void Initiating() throws IOException {
        Properties prop= new Properties();
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\Workspace\\TMS\\selenium\\ZLive\\src\\datadriven.properties");
        prop.load(fis);


        System.out.println("Initiating Browser");

        if (prop.getProperty("browser").equals("firefox"))
        {
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    }
}
```

**data.properties**

```
browser=firefox
url=http://abcd.xxx.in/login
username=32131
pasword=32131
```

Console :

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\ds\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-42991103\testng-customsuite.xml

Initiating Browser

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="loginRelative" id="secondDiv"><label class="loginText">Transport Management System</label>
          <div class="logo-div">
            <div class="loginimageBgStyle"><img src="images/indexImg.png" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="absoluteLeft"></div>
          <div class="absoluteRight"></div><span id="loginForm:loginPanel"><div id="loginForm:messages" class="ui-messages ui-widget errorValidationStyle" aria-live="polite"></div>

          <div class="controls loginTextbox" id="thirdDiv"><div id="loginForm:j_idt16:0:j_idt18" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget"><input id="loginForm:j_idt16:0:username" name="loginForm:j_idt16:0:username" type="text" placeholder="User ID" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /><script id="loginForm:j_idt16:0:username_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("InputText","widget_loginForm_j_idt16_0_username",{id:"loginForm:j_idt16:0:username",widgetVar:"widget_loginForm_j_idt16_0_username"});</script></div>
          </div><div id="loginForm:j_idt16:0:j_idt20" aria-live="polite" class="ui-message ui-helper-hidden"></div><script id="loginForm:j_idt16:0:j_idt20_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("Message","widget_loginForm_j_idt16_0_j_idt20",{id:"loginForm:j_idt16:0:j_idt20",widgetVar:"widget_loginForm_j_idt16_0_j_idt20",target:"loginForm:j_idt16:0:username"});});</script>  

          <div class="controls loginPassword"><div id="loginForm:j_idt16:0:j_idt22" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget"><input id="loginForm:j_idt16:0:password" name="loginForm:j_idt16:0:password" type="password" class="ui-inputfield ui-password ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" placeholder="******" /><script id="loginForm:j_idt16:0:password_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("Password","widget_loginForm_j_idt16_0_password",{id:"loginForm:j_idt16:0:password",widgetVar:"widget_loginForm_j_idt16_0_password"});});</script></div>
                            <!-- &lt;p:keyboard id="" value="" &gt;

                &lt;/p:keyboard&gt; -->
                        </div><div id="loginForm:j_idt16:0:j_idt24" aria-live="polite" class="ui-message ui-helper-hidden"></div><script id="loginForm:j_idt16:0:j_idt24_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("Message","widget_loginForm_j_idt16_0_j_idt24",{id:"loginForm:j_idt16:0:j_idt24",widgetVar:"widget_loginForm_j_idt16_0_j_idt24",target:"loginForm:j_idt16:0:password"});});</script>

          <div><a href="/forgotPassword" class="forgotPwdStyle">Forgot Password?</a>
          </div>

          <div class="loginBtnBgStyle"><button id="loginForm:j_idt28" name="loginForm:j_idt28" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only noBtnStyle" type="button"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c loginBtnImg"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span></button><script id="loginForm:j_idt28_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_loginForm_j_idt28",{id:"loginForm:j_idt28",widgetVar:"widget_loginForm_j_idt28"});</script><button id="loginForm:loginButton" name="loginForm:loginButton" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only loginBtnStyle" onclick="return loginTms();;" type="button"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Login</span></button><script id="loginForm:loginButton_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_loginForm_loginButton",{id:"loginForm:loginButton",widgetVar:"widget_loginForm_loginButton"});</script>
          </div></span><script type="text/javascript">loginTms = function() {PrimeFaces.ab({s:'loginForm:j_idt30',f:'loginForm',u:'loginForm',pa:arguments[0]});}</script>

          <script>
           function TMS_onLoginBtnClick(){

            //alert("localhostinnnn");
            var payroll = $("#payrollIframe").contents();
            payroll.find("#username").val(document.getElementById("loginForm:j_idt15:0:username").value);
            payroll.find("#password").val(document.getElementById("loginForm:j_idt15:0:password").value);
            payroll.find("#user_accounts")[0].submit();
            return false;
           }


           /**
            This method will be called from payroll 
            iframe after success full login
           */
           function loginSuccess(){
              //alert("logged in");
            //TODO: handle here
              loginTms();
           }

           function loginFail(){

            //TODO: handle here
           }
        </script>
        <iframe id="payrollIframe" src="http://localhost/GOPayroll/?source=1" style="opacity:0; height:1px; width:1px;">
        </iframe>

          <div class="logoutMsgStyle">

          </div>


    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What sort of Exception are you getting? Also, are you able to provide your HTML?

Comment: I dont get errors but neither the desired output

Comment: First off, you create `WebDriver` in both classes `Forgetpsw` and `Browsers`. While executing `Browsers` class its `Webdriver` opens your URL. Control is then given back to `Forgetpsw` class where the `WebDriver` has not been initiated, nor assigned. In such case, it will not click anything. Consider passing the `WebDriver` to your `Initiating()` method.

Comment: i found the problem instead of org.testng.annotations.Test i imported  org.junit.Test; and i was debugging testng case hence test method didnt call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `Initiating` method,you need to return the driver object and store it in your Forgetpsw class.

```
public void Initiating() throws IOException {
    Properties prop= new Properties();
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\Workspace\\TMS\\selenium\\ZLive\\src\\datadriven.properties");
    prop.load(fis);


    System.out.println("Initiating Browser");

    if (prop.getProperty("browser").equals("firefox"))
    {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    else
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    return driver;   //return the driver object.
 }
```

And the `Browseropen` method will look like,

```
  public void Browseropen() throws Exception {
    Browsers startup=new  Browsers();
    driver = startup.Initiating();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Initiating() method, u have to return the driver like.

```
public WebDriver Initiating() throws IOException { 
    //your code
    return driver
}
```

and use this returned driver in

```
@BeforeTest
public void Browseropen() throws Exception {
    Browsers startup=new  Browsers();
    this.driver = startup.Initiating(); //your declared driver will get the initialized driver.
}
```

hope this will help you.